incompatible dtype in dataframe
I am developing a python app and I'm working with pandas dataframe. Unfortunately, I have this warning:

"Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an
error in a future version of pandas. Value '[149.7 149.7 149.7 149.7]'
has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a
compatible dtype first. df1.loc[tmp_idx_start:tmp_idx_start+tmp_idx-1,
'AuM'] = (feesPrefinancing.loc[:tmp_idx-1, 'Fees'] +
feesMobiDeferred.loc[:tmp_idx-1, 'Fees'] +
feesLTQDeferred.loc[:tmp_idx-1, 'Fees']).values "

And here is my code :
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(simulationDate, end=feesLTQDeferred['Valuation date'].iloc[-1], freq='MS', inclusive='both').date)

df1['AuM'] = 0. 
df1.loc[4:7, 'AuM'] = (feesPrefinancing.loc[:3, 'Fees'] + feesMobiDeferred.loc[:3, 'Fees'] + feesLTQDeferred.loc[:3, 'Fees']).values
df1.loc[8:, 'AuM'] = (annuities['Invested annuity'].values + feesPrefinancing.loc[4:, 'Fees'].values + feesMobiDeferred.loc[4:, 'Fees'].values + feesLTQDeferred.loc[4:, 'Fees'].values)

As you can guess, I have a dataframe with the first columns being dates and then the second one should contain floats number. That is why I initialized this column with a "0." value (That is also what I read on other post to solve this error). Unfortunately, this warning won't go away even by casting the lines with some "astype" and other things like this.
Here is the result obtain which is correct but I have the warning:
         Date         AuM
0  2023-01-01    0.000000
1  2023-02-01    0.000000
2  2023-03-01    0.000000
3  2023-04-01    0.000000
4  2023-05-01    0.000000
5  2023-06-01    0.000000
6  2023-07-01    0.000000
7  2023-08-01    0.000000
8  2023-09-01  149.700000
9  2023-10-01  149.700000
10 2023-11-01  149.700000
11 2023-12-01  149.700000
12 2024-01-01 2475.800000
13 2024-02-01 2475.800000
14 2024-03-01 2475.800000
15 2024-04-01 2475.800000
16 2024-05-01 2475.800000
17 2024-06-01 2475.800000
18 2024-07-01 2475.800000
19 2024-08-01 2475.800000

Do you have an idea how to solve this ?

Please read [mre] and [edit] your question with sample data that demonstrates the problem.

You assigning data types that are not strictly floats to AuM that is set as a float when initialized with 0.
Assign the correct data type to AuM:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(simulationDate, end=fees:TQDeferred['Valuation date'].iloc[-1], freq='MS', inclusive='both').date)
df1['AuM'] = 0.0
df1.loc[4:7, 'AuM'] = (feesPrefinancing.loc[:3, 'Fees'] + feesMoboDeferred.loc[:3, 'Fees'] + feesLTQDeferred.loc[:3, 'Fees']).astype(np.float64).values
df1.loc[8:, 'AuM'] = (annuities['Invested annuity'] + feesPrefinancing.loc[4:, 'Fees'] + feesMobiDeferred.loc[4:, 'Fees'] + feesLTQDeferred.loc[4:, 'Fees']).astype(np.float64).values


Chech data types of columns involved in the calculus and make sure they're all numeric.
Make sure they are all consistently float64


Cool, it works, but I have one more question, Could this have been avoid by initializing the column differently ?

Yup. Not only you can but you should specify the data type in most practical cases specifically to avoid these kinds of problems. For example: df1['AuM'] = pd.Series(dtype=np.float64)

Okay yes I guess, but for instance if I try to initialize the type with the line you wrote, but I remove the astype(np.float64), I still have the warning. The only way i found to avoid the warnign without the astype is by first write the two lines that set the values for the index 4 to 7 and 8 to the end, and then set the 4 first values to zero. But I don't understand why
